# Creating bundle error on service mix

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, osgi, bundle

I am trying to pack my spring boot application as a bundle in order to use it in service mix.

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.myorg.cxf</groupId>
<artifactId>cxf-demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>bundle</packaging>

<name>cxf-demo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxws</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.felix.bundlerepository</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <Bundle-SymbolicName>GisAdapter</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                    <Private-Package>com.myorg.cxf.cxfdemo*</Private-Package>
                    <Import-Package>*</Import-Package>
                    <Bundle-Activator>com.myorg.cxf.cxfdemo.CxfDemoApplication</Bundle-Activator>
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

This is my pom. I am adding my created JAR(bundle) in deploy folder of service mix. When i try to start the created Bundle it gives me error like missing

```
apache.cxf,org.apache.cxf.jaxws,

org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation,org.springframework.boot,

org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure,org.springframework.context,
                        org.springframework.context.annotation,
                        com.fasterxml.jackson.*,
                        com.fasterxml.jackson.databind,
                        com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation,
                        com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation,
                        com.fasterxml.jackson.core.*,
                        groovy.lang,
                        javax.ejb,
                        javax.validation,
                        javax.*,
                        org.apache.catalina.mbeans,
                        org.apache.catalina.*,
                        org.apache.coyote,
                        org.apache.*,
                        com.sun.msv.grammar,
                        com.sun.msv.grammar.xmlschema,
                        com.sun.msv.reader,
                        com.sun.msv.reader.xmlschema -->
```

This is some of the errors:

```
Error executing command: Error executing command on bundles:
    Error starting bundle 238: Unable to resolve 
 missing requirement ]wiring.package; 
(osgi.wiring.package=org.springframework.boot) Unresolved requirements:  
osgi.wirinage; (osgi.wiring.package=org.springframework.boot)]
```

I tried to add that error in the pom like "Export-Package" and it removes the error, but give me response that something else is missing from the list above and etc.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would like to make a OSGi bundle from a Spring Boot app?

Comment: Because i need to deploy my Spring boot application as a bundle on Service Mix...

Comment: I doubt that will work. Spring boot is not compatible to OSGi. In any case you would need to create bundles from all spring boot libs or embed all in your bundle.. but even then I would not expect it to work.
If you want to deploy to servicemix I recommend to create the application without spring boot.

Comment: I tried to make it without spring but when i deploy it on servicemix as a bundle it shows Active without error and when i try to see the active services it shows: No services was found

Comment: you can try `<Embed-Dependency>*;scope=compile|runtime</Embed-Dependency>` to get rid of the error, but as other comments suggest it will not work. servismix wouldn't know to route the request to spring boot.

Comment: JaxWsServerFactoryBean svrFactory = new JaxWsServerFactoryBean();
       svrFactory.setWsdlLocation("src\\main\\resources\\wsdl\\meternew.wsdl");
       svrFactory.setAddress("http://localhost:9000/Meter");
       svrFactory.setServiceBean(new MeterImpl());
       svrFactory.create();


I am creating my services like this so when i start the app i can access on that site but when i add the jar on service mix it starts the app but i cant access it. I have example code which is working same as this, but the difference is when i try to access my address i am getting no services found.